# SQL : Create one recordset with multiple recordset

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to merge three record into one one.

My query is like this : select Value from table where ID '1'

For now I have the following result :

```
A
B
C
```

Is it possible to have the result like

```
Value1|Value2|Value3

A     | B    | C
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

You can check this.

```
    DECLARE @s VARCHAR(max);
    DECLARE @a VARCHAR(max);
    select 
    @a = 
    stuff((
    select ''',[Value'+ 
            CAST(row_number() over(order by u.username) AS nvarchar(20))+
            ']=''' +
             u.username
    from users u
    for xml path('') 
    ),1,2,'') ;

    set @s = 'select '+@a + ''''
    exec(@s)
```